# How does adding heat cause helium-3 to freeze?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, phase-diagram, low-temperature-physics

[image]

According to here at 3MPa helium-3 actually goes from liquid to solid at 0.1 kelvin, this is the complete opposite of how normal materials behave, how is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I quote from Richardson's article "[The Pomeranchuk Effect](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.69.683?casa_token=SDErvJJrQ6QAAAAA%3Ax5lzMXFCs5biPitQUhjM3OVhQnGgiwJJv3kFgOCArHHkKU6ZtHi-n0jTPNhCp0Ty7tQYOr-DGhLaow)":

*"In 1950, I. Pomeranchuk, a well-known particle theorist, suggested that melting ³He could be cooled by squeezing it. At the time of his
suggestion ³He was quite rare and had not yet even
been liquefied. He observed that at low enough temperatures the thermal phenomena in condensed ³He would be dominated by spin properties instead of phonon properties. The liquid of ³He would obey Fermi statistics with an entropy proportional to the temperature, much like the free electrons in a good metal. On the other hand, the entropy of solid ³He would be that of the disordered collection of weakly interacting spin-1/2 nuclei. At temperatures greater than the (then) expected nuclear-magnetic ordering temperatures less
than 1 mK, the entropy per mole of solid ³He would be
S=R ln 2, independent of temperature until the high-temperature phonon modes of the solid become important. (The Debye temperature of solid ³He is approximately 30 K.)... **The
entropy of solid ³He exceeds that of liquid ³He at temperatures less than 0.3 K.**"* [emph. added]

The [Clausius–Clapeyron relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation) tells us that the pressure–temperature slope for a phase transition is ΔS/ΔV, where ΔS and ΔV are the change in entropy and volume upon transition. With melting/evaporation/sublimation, we typically see an entropy increase coupled with a volume increase, but this is not required; perhaps the most common counterexample is water, which shrinks with melting. This gives the water phase diagram a **reentrant melting slope**, i.e., a negative slope, up to around 2000 atm:

[image]

That same reentrant behavior, in conjunction with the switching of sides such that solid lies on the higher-temperature side, is the aspect of interest in the helium-3 phase diagram:

[image]

In that case, it arises because—unusually—the solid state can have a higher entropy that the liquid state. **The higher-entropy state is always the higher-temperature equilibrium state.** (The reason is that the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy), which Nature tends to minimize, contains a negative coefficient in front of the entropy term. [This ultimately arises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/386789/146039) from Nature's tendency to maximize entropy.) The entropy change ΔS for melting is thus negative under these particular conditions for this particular material.

In *Low-Temperature Physics*, Enss and Hunklinger write

"*...the melting curve of ³He...exhibits a pronounced minimum at a temperature of about
T = 320 mK. ...we can conclude
that the entropy of solid ³He is larger than that of liquid ³He at temperatures below the minimum. ...The essential contribution to the entropy comes from nuclear spins. In the liquid, the entropy
varies at low temperatures proportional to T as expected for a Fermi gas... In solid ³He the atoms are strongly localized and the Fermi-gas
model is not applicable. At high temperatures the orientation of the localized spins is statistical and their contribution to the entropy is S= = R ln 2, where
R is the universal gas constant... With decreasing temperatures
a transition to an antiparallel arrangement of the spins is found. The transition temperature to the antiferromagnetic state is 0.9 mK. At T = 0.32 K,
the temperature at which the minimum occurs, the entropies of liquid and
solid ³He are equal."*

[image]

See also [Farcher's great description of what's happening with the nuclear spins](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410878/146039) from a previous question on this phenomenon.